# XCode availability of button according to current date

Tags: xcode, button, calendar, ios7, disabled-control

I'm wondering is it possible to make one button available in a particular day of the month. The app is something like a calendar and each day is one button. when it is 12 november can I program it user be able to click on day 1 to 12... on 13th of november when he click the button an alert message will appear.

Thanx in advance

Comment: not clear ... What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to use the calendar of the device to set availability of a button. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to create you own calendar, you can create as much buttons a you want. You can set Button1.Enabled = YES or NO in order to enable/disable the button.